# Need help creating a tire

Tags: modeling

I am very new to Blender so please excuse my ignorance about the program. I am trying to create a tire (which is a tractor tire) for a model and am having trouble creating it. I will attach a picture of what I am trying to create and a picture of what I have been able to do.

I first start with cylinder which I hollow, then change the vertices to 30. I add a split down the center with the R key, and the rotate it along the X axis to achieve the correct tread angle. My next objective is to get the tread to "stick out"

I can get the correct angle of the tread, but I can't get the tread to "stick out". I have added more vertices that stick out and I tried to merge the vertices to achieve the look, but it doesn't work correctly.

I have searched countless videos and can't seem to find what I need to do. Any help is appreciated[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: please check on this link, it really helpfull the learn how to create a tire, this one is the link : [how to create tire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a90cYLEbpi4)

Comment: I have followed that video but what is different for my tire is that the tread angles back to the bottom of the last tread instead of it all sticking out like a square.

Comment: checkout these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQC3_dJ7llI&t=24s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqkUgM0dHgA

Answer (score 4):

You can create one segment of your tire:

[image]

Array it with the *Array* modifier:

[image]

Bend it with the *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode):

[image]

Comment: +1 ...but...he is very new to Blender. Maybe you should explain a bit more how you made your first picture. Because as i know you, you made it with 4 clicks and pressed 5 buttons and i have also no idea how you made that... ;)

Comment: Whaat? Haven't you seen my video? https://youtu.be/Njj1D639C48

Comment: Damn...you are even successful in the tire industry...i cannot believe what industries you are dominating....!!!

Comment: oh by the way, I've just bought a small company called Blender.Fun, I thought you may be interested to know

Comment: Thank you for the response but what you explained is way over my head, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @moonboots: i would have known that, because that i would have became a billionaire... ;)

Comment: @moonboots: maybe you should make the tire explanation video in english too... ;)

Comment: @moonboots: i don't wanna say "i told you" but i told you... :D :D he is a beginner and your explanation prerequisites a lot of knowledge... ;)

Comment: @Chris yes but a detailed explanation would be much too long  :/

Comment: make a yt video and link it additionally. You will have trillions of views, become richer  than Musk and the you can buy amazon, google and facebook....

Comment: then maybe, maybe, I'll be able to buy Blender.Fun...

Comment: @moonboots: yes maybe, but then the Blender.Fun company burns all your money and you will be poor again... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let me just add my own approach, I'm not going to tell you exactly how to model that tire but this may be useful for you.

First, enable LoopTool under Preferences -> Addons.

Make a cylinder at world origin, select the bottom and top face, inset them to the correct tire thickness, and right click --> Loop tools --> Bridge. Then scale the tire cylinder down on the Z axis. You should get something like this:

[image]

Then, go to the top view by pressing that blue Z button in the top right (or however you like to do it), go into edit mode, select ALL the vertices of the cylinder (by pressing A), and choose the Bisect tool on the left tool bar, which is under the Knife tool (press T if you don't see the tool bar).

[image]

With all the vertices selected, bisect with left click, and open the menu that pops up on the bottom left, and 0 out all values but Y and axis threshold, and hit Clear Inner (or Clear Outer):

[image]

Then, open up the console window:

[image]

And now decide how many slices of the tire you want. Let's say we want 20, so we type in 360 / 20, and we get 18 from the console. You can also use Google for this of course.

Now, rotate the tire on the Z by whatever the console outputted, so in this case 18 degrees, and then bisect again using the same values as before, and play with Clear Inner or Outer to get what you want:

[image]

Then, press `Alt` `D`, `R`, `Z`, and then type the degree amount, 18, then press `Enter`. Do all of this without clicking or pressing Enter in between the strokes. Then press Shift R however many times it takes to complete the circle, then go into edit mode on one of the meshes, and edit how you please. Ta daa! Live radial array without the stupid modifiers that don't work 80% of the time.

[image]

If you want the mesh to rotate around a specific point, either change the pivot point to 3D cursor and place the 3D cursor where you want, or have it stay at median point and place the origin of the object where you want it to rotate by.

If you didn't press `Alt` `D` the first time to duplicate, then you can simply select all the meshes, press `Control` `L` --> `Link Object Data`.

Once you're done with the mesh, you can join them all together, go into edit mode, enable Auto Merge under `Tool` --> `Options`, select all the vertices of the mesh, and move them all by 0 by pressing G and left clicking without moving your mouse.

Comment: Thank you Lukas, I will try this. This might be a stupid question but is this tire possible to model 100%? Please excuse my inexperience.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's simply one bit duplicated around. So you just need to model that one bit, but you have to make sure it tiles correctly, and that no seems are visible. Take a look at this: https://imgur.com/Jv6pFZ9.png That for example is what you model. Just make sure it tiles bottom and top.

Comment: Ok thanks. What will the action be called to raise the tiles up but on just one end? Just like how the tread will be?

Comment: I'm not sure, extruding?